# AWK - suppress stdout on system() function

Tags: awk

I'm currently writing a shell script that will be given a directory, then output an ls of that directory with the return code from a C program appended to each line.  The C program only needs to be called for regular files.

The problem I'm having is that output from the C program is cluttering up the output from awk, and I can't get stdout to redirect to /dev/null inside of awk.  I have no use for the output, I just need the return code.  Speed is definitely a factor, so if you have a more efficient solution I'd be happy to hear it.  Code follows:

```
directory=$1
ls -i --full-time $directory | awk '
{
    rc = 0
    if (substr($2,1,1) == "-") {
        dbType=system("cprogram '$directory'/"$10)
    }
    print $0 " " rc
}
'
```

Comment: Have you tried: `dbType=system("cprogram '$directory'/"$10" >/dev/null")` ?

Comment: @John1024 that might remove your home directory and everything below it or do just about anything else depending on the contents of the input file so I wouldn't do it.

Comment: @EdMorton +1 for your answer.  The OP wrote "I can't get stdout to redirect to /dev/null inside of awk" and I was trying to find out what he meant.

Comment: Got it, I mainly meant to give the OP a heads up that he's GOT to start using quotes in his shell scripts or he'll be very sorry one day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is not shell so you cant just use a shell variable inside an awk script, and in shell always quote your variables. Try this:

```
directory="$1"
ls -i --full-time "$directory" | awk -v dir="$directory" '
{
    rc = 0
    if (substr($2,1,1) == "-") {
        rc = system("cprogram \"" dir "/" $10 "\" >/dev/null")
    }
    print $0, rc
}
'
```

Oh and, of course, don't actually do this. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

I just spent a minute thinking about what your script is actually doing and rather than trying to use awk as a shell and parse the output of ls, it looks like the solution you REALLY want would be more like:

```
directory="$1"
find "$directory" -type f -maxdepth 1 -print |
while IFS= read -r dirFile
do
    op=$(ls -i --full-time "$dirFile")
    cprogram "$dirFile" >/dev/null
    rc="$?"
    printf "%s %s\n" "$op" "$rc"
done
```

and you could probably save a step by using the `-printf` arg for `find` to get whatever info you're currently using `ls` for.